# Make vim read the vimrc from ~/.vim/vimrc

Tags: terminal

This may not be the best place to ask this question but I'm having trouble getting vim to read my vimrc file. If I have it in the home directory as ~/.vimrc then it ready just fine but if I move it ~/.vim/vimrc so that I can take advantage of plugins and a few other things, it no longer reads the vimrc. I can't remember what I was supposed to do to make it read the correct vimrc.

Comment: You should explain more about 'take advantage of plugins', because nothing I know of would prefer you from using ~/.vimrc for everything.

Comment: When I was in Ubuntu and I started using vim plugins it had me make a .vim directory and inside that a plugins directory and move my .vimrc to the .vim directory

Comment: I used to use vimbuddy (before I had plugins that actually did something functional), installed in ~/.vim/plugins, and I just used `source ~/.vim/plugins/vimbuddy.vim` from within my ~/.vimrc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method of blindly loading all your plugins, assuming they are all in ~/.vim/plugins, would be putting the following in your ~/.vimrc:

```
source glob(~/.vim/plugins/*.vim)
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a symlink.

`ln -s ~/.vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc`

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to remain using a ~/.vimrc file, if for no other reason than using it to read in your sub-folder based .vimrc

Putting something like the below in your ~/.vimrc should work:

```
if filereadable("~/.vim/vimrc")
        source ~/.vim/vimrc
endif
```

I don't recall if vim expands home directories or not. I imagine it does, but if it does not, just use:

```
if filereadable("/Users/yourusername/.vim/vimrc")
        source /Users/yourusername/.vim/vimrc
endif
```